# why are RTLD_DEEPBIND and RTLD_LOCAL not preventing collision of static class member symbol

Tags: c++, linux, dlopen

I am trying to write a simple plugin system for an application and would like to prevent plugins from stomping on each others symbols, however RTLD_DEEPBIND and RTLD_LOCAL don't seem to be enough when it comes to static class members when they happen to have the same name in different plugins.

I wrote a stripped down example to show what I mean.
I compiled and ran it like this:

```
g++ -c dumb-plugin.cpp -std=c++17 -fPIC
gcc -shared dumb-plugin.o -o dumb1.plugin
cp dumb1.plugin dumb2.plugin
g++ main.cpp -ldl -o main
./main
```

And the content of the output file for the second plugin showed that it reused the the class from the first plugin.

How can I avoid this?

EDIT: I compiled the plugin with clang(not main just the plugin) and it worked despite all of the RTLD_DEEPBIND stuff being in main.cpp which was still compiled with g++. It didn't work when the plugin was compiled with gcc 10.3 or 11.1 even when I tried -Bsymbolic. Is this a bug?

If I run readelf on the DSO compiled/linked with clang i see these 2 lines:

```
21: 00000000000040b0     4 OBJECT  UNIQUE DEFAULT   26 _ZN9DumbClass7co[...]_ZN9DumbClass7co[...]
25: 00000000000040b0     4 OBJECT  UNIQUE DEFAULT   26 _ZN9DumbClass7co[...]
```

and with gcc i get:

```
20: 00000000000040a8     4 OBJECT  WEAK   DEFAULT   24 _ZN9DumbClass7co[...]
27: 00000000000040a8     4 OBJECT  WEAK   DEFAULT   24 _ZN9DumbClass7co[...]
```

with WEAK instead of UNIQUE under the BIND column.

dumb-plugin.cpp:

```
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>

int global_counter = 0;
static int static_global_counter = 0;

std::string replace_slashes(const char * str) {
    std::string s;
    for (const char* c = str; *c != '\0'; c++)
        s += (*c == '/')?
            '#' : *c;
    return s;
}

void foo() {}

class DumbClass {
    public:
        static inline int counter = 0;
};

extern "C" void plugin_func() {
    static int static_local_counter = 0;

    Dl_info info;
    dladdr((void*)foo, &info);

    std::string path = "plugin_func() from: " + replace_slashes(info.dli_fname);
    auto fp = std::fopen(path.c_str(), "w");

    fprintf(fp, "static local counter: %d\n",  static_local_counter++);
    fprintf(fp, "DumbClass::counter: %d\n",    DumbClass::counter++);
    fprintf(fp, "global counter: %d\n",        global_counter++);
    fprintf(fp, "static global counter: %d\n", static_global_counter++);

    std::fclose(fp);
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>


int main () {
    char path1[512], path2[512];
    getcwd(path1, 512);
    strcat(path1, "/dumb1.plugin");
    getcwd(path2, 512);
    strcat(path2, "/dumb2.plugin");

    auto h1 = dlopen(path1, RTLD_NOW | RTLD_LOCAL | RTLD_DEEPBIND);
    auto h2 = dlopen(path2, RTLD_NOW | RTLD_LOCAL | RTLD_DEEPBIND);

    auto func = (void(*)())  dlsym(h1, "plugin_func");
    func();
    func =      (void(*)())  dlsym(h2, "plugin_func");
    func();
}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce. I get 0 in both files.

Comment: @273K weird, did you use gcc/g++?

Comment: Yes. I would move class DumbClass to unnamed namespace.

Comment: @273K i don't want to add unenforceable requirements for end users trying to write simple plugins, especially since it can create errors in other plugins, i tried using a different version of gcc and got the same result.. even when i added another extern function to one of the plugins to make the binary different incase there was some weird hash check, i even passed -Bsymbolic with all of the compilation and linking commands and it still happened...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`gcc` implements static inline data members (and also static data members of class templates, inline or not, and static variables in inline functions, and perhaps other things as well) as *global unique symbols* (a GNU extension to the ELF format). There is only one such symbol with a given name per process, by design.

`clang` implements such things as normal weak symbols. These will not collide when RTLD_LOCAL and RTLD_DEEPBIND are used.

There are several ways to avoid collisions, but all of them require plugin writers to take an action. The best way IMO is to use [hidden symbol visibility by default](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility), only opening symbols that are meant to be `dlsym`d.

Comment: thanks, so i was on the right track... i think i'll just tell users to use -fno-gnu-unique (https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gcc.1.html) if they use gcc.
since -fno-gnu-unique also changes the abi from 3(gnu linux) to 0(generic) i'll check the os abi in the plugins header before i dlopen it and reject plugins that don't have it set to 0. unless there's a better check or way to force it at runtime.

from what i can tell -fno-gnu-unique basically just makes gcc behave like other compilers in defiance of the c++ standard.